Can I swap a gravel wheel with 1x10 cassette for a new road wheel with 1x12?
I'm thinking about buying new set of wheels for my Topstone 4. I'm currently using default wheels with changed tires and default 1x10 cassette and ideally I would want to put new road wheel with 1x12 cassette in its place while swapping only chain. Would that even be possible without changing shifter and other stuff or would I have to stick to x10 cassette? Would it even be that much of a difference riding road wheels with 11-48 cassette than 10-50? I'm not experienced with this stuff.

No, your derailleur/shifter is indexed for 10 speeds, not 12 (spacing between cogs is smaller in 12-speed cassettes).

Would it even be that much of a difference riding road wheels with 11-48 casette than 10-50? Climbs should be lil bit less comfy I guess because of bigger differences between shifts but overall if I'm used to x10 gears would I be fine with same microshift casette on road wheels?

The difference when climbing would be marginal. The 11T small sprocket would be more of an issue on the road, especially if riding with roadies (I'm doing it as well with 2x11, the 46-11 combination is fine in most cases, but in peloton, I wouldn't mind an extra cog sometimes - a 40-11 would feel limiting more often).

You have 10 speeds on your cassette, so any other wheel also requires 10 speeds, no more and no less will work.
If you want to convert your existing setup to completely 12 speed then you'll need a new right-hand shifter, and a new rear derailleur.   And a 12 speed chain and cassette.  There's a good chance the 12 speed cassette will go on your 10 speed wheel, but it might not so confirm that first.
Finally - the price of all these new parts may represent a significant percentage of a replacement bike specced as you want it to be.  It may be worth on-selling your existing bike and putting the proceeds toward a new 12 speed bike like you want.

There's a good chance the 12 speed cassette will go on your 10 speed wheel, but it might not so confirm that first there you enter into a sensitive compatibility topic: the main benefit in this configuration would to have a 10T small sprocket, but that requires a different free hub body. I'm not sure there are many cassette options that would work with a standard HG freehub body and a 12S chain (in gravel 12S, SRAM uses flattop chains and Shimano Hyperglide+ chains, for which the original cassettes require different freehub bodies - SRAM has a 12S 11-44 flattop cassette though).

@Renaud:  Shimano 12s road (HG+) cassettes are compatible with 11s freehub bodies.

@Michael Indeed, and by extension the 2x GRX one (that is for me more a rugged road groupset than a pure gravel one). But in 1x, Microspline is mandatory for all 12S Shimano MTB/Gravel cassettes (as I wrote, compatibility in 12S is a sensitive topic ;)).
